# ISO 8601 week numbers on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, settings, iso

I like seeing week numbers on my iPhone’s Calendar app, but they display in *Gregorian* form. I use the *ISO 8601* format for my work, which is slightly different, but an international standard. Yet I cannot find a setting to change this.

[image: side-by-side screenshots showing an iPhone Calendar app versus a calendar in a Wikipedia entry]

If I wanted a Japanese or Buddhist calendar, however, that wouldn’t be problem!

[image: screenshot of iOS Settings app showing Calendar options]

Certainly some iPhone users around the globe also need an ISO 8601 calendar for this built-in app. **Is there any way for me to get it to work on my device?**

A couple notes:

- I’m not interested in learning about other apps that do have this option. My question is about the official Apple iPhone Calendar app.
- The *macOS* [has an option](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209340/72448) to change from Gregorian to ISO 8601. It seems odd to me that this option wouldn’t extend to Apple’s mobile devices too. Maybe changing it on my Mac will cause it to change on my iPhone? IDK.

Comment: I've previously set macOS to use ISO 8601 based on that same link, and today I noticed my iPhone was using mismatching week numbers, indicating they are not linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like "Gregorian" on iOS uses different week numbering depending on your region.

I had my phone region set to New Zealand, and was seeing the non-ISO week numbering. Changing the region to Finland seems to switch to ISO week numbers, even though the calendar is still set to Gregorian (and still with only Japanese and Buddhist as the other options).

[image: iOS settings screenshot, region set to New Zealand] [image: iOS calendar screenshot, current week number showing as 8]

[image: iOS settings screenshot, region set to Finland]
[image: iOS calendar screenshot, current week number showing as 7]

#### Sidenote / rant:

This feels like a case of Apple being too clever by half; reducing configurability for the sake of simplicity, but leading to a confusing user experience.

I'm not even sure its assumption about NZ week numbering conventions are correct, but I can't find any authoritative source on that. [Wikipedia indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Other_week_numbering_systems) that "most of Asia and Oceania" uses ISO 8601, but that section has also been tagged as dubiously sourced. Maybe it's just the case that these conventions are hard to pin down for regions where they aren't as commonly used? *Maybe they should be configurable?*

Note also how in Finland you get to configure a number format, while in NZ you don't. Meanwhile, you *can't* configure the clock separator, which is my biggest gripe with Finnish formatting standards.

In conclusion, you may need to go region-shopping for a while before you find one with your preferred week numbering, in addition to your other non-configurable format preferences.